# Wi-Fi ad hoc connection times out

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-vista

I have this issue on Windows Vista: whenever I create an ad hoc network, any devices that are connected to this network will lose conection once they become idle. When searching for the ad hoc network again, the network doesn't come up, and reconnecting is impossible.

Any suggestions on what could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your devices just going idle, or are they going to sleep?

Once a second device joins a Wi-Fi "ad hoc" (technically "IBSS") network, the devices completely share responsibility for the network; that is, the original creator of the network doesn't have any special role in keeping the network alive.

Most Wi-Fi implementors don't like to re-publish an IBSS network after sleep/wake if no one else is already publishing it, because it can cause zombie IBSS networks that never die.

For example, if you ever see a network named "Free Public WiFi", it is almost certainly yet another instance of the most famous zombie IBSS network of all time. People keep joining it in places like airports and cafés thinking they'll be able to get online, but now their machine will perpetuate the problem. I've heard this jokingly referred to as "the IBSS virus" within the Wi-Fi industry (it's not really a computer virus, there's no malware involved, it's just an emergent behavior of less-than-ideal IBSS implementations).

So if all of your devices participating in the IBSS go to sleep, leaving no one to keep it alive, it's no surprise that the network is discontinued. As I said, smart IBSS implementations won't publish an IBSS on wake, but they may join it if they see someone else in range still publishing it.

Even if your devices aren't fully going into system sleep, I could imagine that some battery-operated mobile devices might put their radios into low-power mode when they don't have any network traffic to send or receive, and in this low-power mode they might not help keep the IBSS alive. So if there is ever a moment where they all put their radios to sleep because the network is idle, then the network disappears.

The solution is most likely to put one of your devices into AP mode, instead of IBSS mode. Most mobile devices that have "personal hotspot" mode use real AP mode instead of IBSS mode for that. Macs with Internet Sharing enabled "From: <whatever>, To: Wi-Fi" will also use real AP mode instead of IBSS mode.